# How do I complete the Boss Mansion Bonus Stage?

Tags: pacman-world-repac

I am struggling to complete the bonus stage for the Boss Mansion levels. In the original Pacman World 20th Anniversary, this bonus stage was annoying, but actually quite easy. In Repac, they've upped the challenge on it. The pattern is different, and although the blue coffins hang around longer, it's still difficult for me to complete. So, how do I best complete the Bonus Stage for the Boss Mansion levels?